# Rewriting a contradictory ZX loop into an independent pi node

Tags: zx-calculus

Consider the following ZX graph:

[image]

If you perform tensor contraction on this graph, you get the zero tensor. Therefore it should be equivalent to this graph:

[image]

**How do you rewrite the graph, axiom by axiom, to get from the attached loop to the independent node?**

What I do know how to do is to pump a $\pi$ node and some scalar factors out of the loop. This is enough to e.g. make PyZX simplify the graph into different results depending on which rewrites I've applied to the graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to setup a situation where the hopf law disconnects the pi part from the line part.

[image]

[image]